# update sql scripts from visual studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

We have 10 members in developer team, they are building windows application, we are using team foundation server for source control.

Application uses sql server, sql server will be on customer's server machine.

I want to ask, how developers update scripts when they create tables or store procedures. And how to take care about conflicts?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to create table-update scripts when you use ORMs like entity framework or nHibernate (unless you have to move data from one column/table to another), the framework should do that for you, if you tell it to (that's the only reason I still have nHibernate in my code), usually on app-startup, but you can also transfer this functionality to an external program that you call manually (warning: error-prone).

And you should always use the database-first method, because your data-structures are way way more important than your code.

Stored procedures, functions and views you just drop them all and recreate them (in order of dependency), everything else is too much work and too error prone. SSMS has this function to create scripts for drop/create views/stored procedures etc, but it doesn't get the order of dependencies right, so you have to test that and correct it manually, unless you write your own tool (i recommend it, but it's difficult - dependency resolution requires Topological Sorter and regex).

As for revision control, that's a problem if several people work on a database simultanously.

RedGate has TFS revision control integration for SQL-Server / SSMS, don't know if they have already updated if for SQL-2012/2014, but I would bet that they have.

In order to minimize collisions, I suggest when in office you all develop on the same database, except for the cases where that is not possible.

Comment: thanks for your help, what if database table has to be created dynamically? When client exe starts database tables has to be created..